# How to crop the png image and remove its unused space using Canvas in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout, custom-painting, flutter-canvas

This attachment is from the rendered canvas image which is saved locally via canvas. In image I have drawn the square box which I want to render in canvas and save locally **without left and right extra spaces**. I just want to save the square box and remove that unnecessary space of PNG-image. So, how to do this?

[image]

**widget-source-code:**

```
  return CustomPaint(
    painter: PngImageCropper(image: image),
  );
```

**PngImageCropper-code**

```
  class PngImageCropper extends CustomPainter {
    PngImageCropper({
      this.image,
    });

    ui.Image image;

    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      _drawCanvas(size, canvas);
      _saveCanvas(size);
    }

    Canvas _drawCanvas(Size size, Canvas canvas) {
      final center = Offset(image.width / 2, image.height / 2);

      double drawImageWidth = 0;
      double drawImageHeight = 0;

      Rect rect =
          Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: _getCircularRadius(image));
      Path path = Path()..addOval(rect);

      canvas.clipPath(path);
      Paint paint = new Paint();

      canvas.drawImage(
        image,
        Offset(drawImageWidth, drawImageHeight),
        paint,
      );

      return canvas;
    }

    _getCircularRadius(ui.Image image) {
      return image.height > image.width
          ? image.width.toDouble() / 2
          : image.height.toDouble() / 2;
    }

    _saveCanvas(Size size) async {
      var pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
      var canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
      var paint = Paint();
      paint.isAntiAlias = true;

      _drawCanvas(size, canvas);

      var pic = pictureRecorder.endRecording();
      ui.Image img = await pic.toImage(image.width, image.height);
      var byteData = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var buffer = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      // var response = await get(imgUrl);
      var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File(join(documentDirectory.path,
          '${DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String()}.png'));
      file.writeAsBytesSync(buffer);

      print(file.path);
    }

    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you need `CustomPainter` for? you want to save circular image only? without black frame?

Comment: Cause I have the to some image manipulation and have to render that manipulated image and save it to local storage.

Comment: Waao! Awesome It works.

Comment: Hello @pskink Is there any Listener to listen when the CustomPainter paint(..) task is completed? I have to rebuild the widget as soon as the paint(..) task is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Worked source code!** Answer by @pskink.

```
  Future<List<int>> cropRonded(ui.Image image) async {
    var recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    var canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    var imageSize = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    var boundsToCrop = Rect.fromCenter(
        center: imageSize.center(Offset.zero),
        width: imageSize.shortestSide,
        height: imageSize.shortestSide);
    var matrix = Matrix4.translationValues(
            -boundsToCrop.topLeft.dx, -boundsToCrop.topLeft.dy, 0)
        .storage;
    var paint = Paint()
      ..shader = ImageShader(image, TileMode.clamp, TileMode.clamp, matrix);
    var radius = imageSize.shortestSide / 2;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(radius, radius), radius, paint);


    ui.Image cropped = await recorder
        .endRecording()
        .toImage(imageSize.shortestSide.toInt(), imageSize.shortestSide.toInt());
    var byteData = await cropped.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

Comment: Can you do an example for rectangular crop ?